HTML became XML
I uploaded a static web (HTML, CSS, Javascript) to the internet using google cloud hosting, but the browser (chrome) keeps displaying it as an XML file instead of HTML file, how can I fix that?
I uploaded it as an HTML file but Chrome reads it like it was XML

Please check that your HTML starts as follows: <!DOCTYPE html><html>...

Does it have a file extension?  Eg "mypage.xml"

Can you include the first few lines of your file here?  A link to the site as well (not instead) may help, not withstanding: can I provide a link to my site

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Make sure your HTML (.html) file begins with the following doctype declaration:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

Here are the recommended W3C doctype declarations:

Recommended Doctype Declarations to use in your Web document.

Also, make sure that the first line is not:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


my html file starts with . the problem is with the google cloud hosting.

In the VS code that line does not appear -  -  but when I check the web sources in the browser that line is the first

@אמיתיקילמן Check out this: xml is shown instead of site and Google's Host a static website guide.
